# Toggle Value in Angular Material CheckBox

Tags: angular-material2, angular

I have a Template Driven Form in which i am putting a checkbox that can toggle its value.

Component

```
public toggles = [
    { value: 'toggled', display: 'Toggled' },
    { value: 'untoggled', display: 'UnToggled' },
];

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="toggle" [(ngModel)]="user.toggle">
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                [checked]="user.toggle === toggles[0].value" 
                (change)="$event.target.checked? (user.toggle =  toggles[0].value) : (user.toggle = toggles[1].value)">
            {{ toggles[0].display }}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following works great, but when i am switching to Angular Material it just fails to works .

The material Template code

```
<input type="hidden" name="toggle" [(ngModel)]="user.toggle">
<md-checkbox [checked]="user.toggle === toggles[0].value"
               (change)="$event.target.checked?(user.toggle = toggles[0].value): (user.toggle = toggles[1].value)">
    {{toggles[0].display}}</md-checkbox>
```

I am getting the following Error in console, it says cannot read the property of undefined  console,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined
        at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (TemplateDrivenComponent.html:64)
```

I know the point where the error is occurring **$event.target.checked** angular cannot read this checked event on md-checkbox , how to get around this any pointers will be great

thanks

Comment: well, what is the value of $event.target ?

Comment: the value of $event.target is coming from the checkbox property as in the code without material it checks if the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: I know WHAT it is... but what is its VALUE

Comment: log the object you're trying to view the properties of, and it will probably shed light on what is going wrong

Comment: also why not just use `this`?

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley the value is coming fine in console like checked:true

Comment: then that is not where the problem is. the error you posted says that `$event.target` is undefined, so how and where are you logging it?

Comment: thanks @TheRealMrCrowley the error was using $event.target using it like $event.checked did the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at comments try the following hope this solves the issue i guess you need not use target with event in Material.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="toggle" [(ngModel)]="user.toggle">
        <md-checkbox [checked]="user.toggle === toggles[0].value"
                       (change)="$event.checked?(user.toggle = toggles[0].value): (user.toggle = toggles[1].value)">
            {{toggles[0].display}}</md-checkbox>
```